# Ansible inconsistent value for ansible_fqdn

Tags: ansible, hostname

The variable `{{ansible_fqdn}}` can take two different values: the server's short name (server300) or its long name (server300.prod.x.y.z).
When we use this variable in the playbook to retrieve a file `{{ansible_fqdn}}.crt`, depending on the value chosen, the file can be not found, and the playbook will fail.
To have a consistent value for hostnames over a list of servers, should one rather use `{{ansible_hostname}}` (short hostname from linux command `uname -n`) and `{{inventory_hostname}}` (long hostname from "hosts" file) instead?
Or is there a way to obtain a consistent value from `{{ansible_fqdn}}`?

Comment: Those are all different values for different situation and the one to use depends on your exact requirement. `ansible_fqdn` and `ansible_hostname`  are collected during facts gathering after a successful connection to the target. Their content come from calling different functions. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/38777 for a start of a discussion. Anyway, the content will be the one you discover. `inventory_hostname` is the name you set yourself in your inventory. If that name contains dots, you can use `inventory_hostname_short` which will return the chars before the first dot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: ***"The variable {{ ansible_fqdn }} can take two different values: the server's short name (server300) or its long name (server300.prod.x.y.z)."***

A: It depends on how you configure [*hostname*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/uname.html). Take a look at `uname -n`. Either it is long

```sh
[admin@test_23 ~]$ uname -n
test_23.example.com

shell> ansible test_23 -m setup | grep ansible_fqdn
        "ansible_fqdn": "test_23.example.com",
```

, or it is short

```sh
[admin@test_11 ~]$ uname -n
test_11

shell> ansible test_11 -m setup | grep ansible_fqdn
        "ansible_fqdn": "test_11",
```

---

Q: ***"Should one rather use {{ ansible_hostname }} (short hostname from linux command uname -n) and {{ inventory_hostname }} (long hostname from "hosts" file) instead?"***

A: It depends on how you configure the [*inventory*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html). The variable *ansible_hostname* is not required. If you don't run [*setup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) (or get the variables from a [*cache*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#cache-plugins)) and if you don't declare it explicitly it won't be defined, e.g.

```sh
shell> cat hosts
test_23

shell> ansible test_23 -m debug -a var=inventory_hostname
test_23 | SUCCESS => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_23"
}
shell> ansible test_23 -m debug -a var=ansible_hostname
test_23 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_hostname": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

You can declare [*alias*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-aliases) and *ansible_hostname*, e.g.

```sh
shell> cat hosts
alias_of_test_23 ansible_hostname=test_23

shell> ansible alias_of_test_23 -m debug -a var=inventory_hostname
alias_of_test_23 | SUCCESS => {
    "inventory_hostname": "alias_of_test_23"
}
shell> ansible alias_of_test_23 -m debug -a var=ansible_hostname
alias_of_test_23 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_hostname": "test_23"
}
```

If you run *setup* the value of *ansible_hostname* is the short hostname from the command `uname -n`, e.g.

```sh
shell> cat hosts
alias_of_test_23 ansible_host=test_23.example.com

shell> ansible alias_of_test_23 -m setup | grep ansible_hostname
        "ansible_hostname": "test_23",
```

---

Q: ***"Or is there a way to obtain a consistent value from {{ ansible_fqdn }}?"***

A: There are more options:

- At remote hosts, configure hostnames to provide you with the FQDN
- In the inventory, declare the FQDN form of aliases and use *inventory_hostname*
- If the options above are not feasible you'll have to declare a custom variable.

The consistency is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some interesting information from the official documentation regarding hosts : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables

I recommend using the inventory_hostname as you define it yourself.
Since you also define the address in the inventory, you can set that in the hostfile. Given an inventory snippet:

```
---
mariadb-servers:
  hosts:
    mariadb1.example.com:
      ansible_host: 1.2.3.4 # IP for the hostname, external or internal
      ansible_user: ubuntu

  vars:
    mariadb_target_group: mariadb-servers
```

Then as a pre_task you can have something like:

```
- name: Build hosts file
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    regexp: '.*{{ item }}$'
    line: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }} {{ item }}"
    state: present
    mode: "0644"
  when: hostvars[item].ansible_host is defined
  loop: "{{ groups[mariadb_target_group] }}"
```

That way the name of the server is consistent and it will also resolve to what you set without the need for DNS ( which you may or may not want ).
The other suggestion for setting up the hostname properly to be the FQDN can be done on top of this if needed.

Various tools use various ways to get the hostname, so it is best to be consistent from setup of the host.
With the fqdn set properly on Linux, you will also have consistent output for ansible_fqdn.